# Gene set enrichment analysis (GSEA) for Bio-Rad Bio-Plex human cytokine screening panel

Tags: bioinformatics

We have analyzed the effects of several peptides, separately, on peripheral blood mononuclear cells (PBMCs). We have analyzed changes in the level of cytokines secretion in response to incubation with the peptides. The assay was performed on a Bio-Rad Bio-Plex platform with a Bio-Plex Pro Human Cytokine 48-plex Screening Panel kit. So now we have information about the changes in the secretion of 48 cytokines by PBMCs in response to incubation with any of the peptides. I would like to know if there is any way to analyze the obtained results in a kind of gene set enrichment analysis (GSEA) in order to determine, for example, the type of cells that predominantly produce the significantly changed cytokines, or, for example, signals of what processes are the changed cytokines? If there is no such program or web-service yet, then maybe someone can advise a meaningful explanatory review or a small book to understand and interpret the changes obtained at the level of cytokines into some kind of biological hypothesis about the effect of the tested peptides on the immunocompetent cells of the bloodstream?

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind is doing a kind of differential expression analysis across your tested protein conditions, clustering by cytokine secretion and using a database such as string analysis to determine protein-group interactions: https://string-db.org/cgi/input?sessionId=bpz0SAZRwcoA&input_page_active_form=multiple_identifiers.

You could hypothetically do some sort of enrichment analysis if you had a cytokine set list for a specific pathway/cell-population vs your ranked cytokine secretion list.